# How to send the xml to mongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

i am trying to send an xml.bz2 file to mongodb and i am using Mac and writing everything in the terminal.

In the https://github.com/spencermountain/wikipedia-to-mongodb there is a step 4 that i stucked,

> ## 4 get going
>
> load it into mongo (10-15 minutes)
>
> wikipedia-to-mongodb ./afwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2

I have a directory called wikipedia-to-mongodb and i downloaded file with wget. I connected mongod,

when i write the terminal that `$ wikipedia-to-mongodb ./afwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2` it is not working. What am i doing wrong? I am kind of new this environment.

I tried 2 inputs below you can see it

**1)**

input=  `./afwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2`

> [thread1] SyntaxError: missing name after . operator @(shell):1:22

**2)**

input=  `wikipedia-to-mongodb ./afwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2`

> -bash: wikipedia-to-mongodb: command not found

Comment: This isn't a mongodb question - this is about some 3rd-party tool. Perhaps post an issue to their repo?

Comment: @DavidMakogon i am asking that ./blabla.xml.bz2 can load into mongodb?

Comment: @M.J.Watson You can load whatever you want into mongodb, as long as it consists of bytes. Either into a normal document or into GridFS. The question is: what do you want to do with the data? Please be more specific here, and do not use links. If that link changes or becomes unavailable, your question does not make any sense any more. As well as the answer.

Comment: I found the solution i converted into json.